# Unchecked assignment when initializing a list

Tags: java

What is the difference between

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList();
```

and

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

?

In the first case, the IDE highlights it and says "Unchecked assignment", but they seem to behave exactly the same.

Comment: `List<>` is a generic type, and generic types should always be used with diamond operator. You use it as raw type, so thats why IDE complains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No difference, java compiler could figure out the type, but better add the inferred type argument:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: IDEA will complain about that too.   He will suggest new ArrayList<>()

Comment: There is a difference. The first one (new ArrayList();) is wrong. The second (new ArrayList<>();) is correct. ArrayList<String>() would also be fine, but the first one is definitely incorrectly defined.

Answer (score 2):

The type of each entry in the ArrayList has not been specified, only the List, hence why the `Unchecked assignment` warning. You should explicitly state it in one of two ways...

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Or, you can abbreviate that now (since Java 7) to...

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

...and the compiler will then be able to implicitly pick up the type from the List's type designation.

Comment: Yep.  See See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html